# Problem with migrating an Azure database for a Ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, azure

I have a working Ruby on Rails app (running Ruby 2.2.10p489 and Rails 4.2.5 and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.2.6) on a Linux server (Amazon AMI v 2018.03 rhel fedora). It connects to an Azure database. Everything works great. But when I migrate to a different Azure database and change the credentials to point to the new database, I get a long list of unhelpful errors that looks like so:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/tiny_tds-1.0.5/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:53:in `connect'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/tiny_tds-1.0.5/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:53:in `initialize'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:280:in `new'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:280:in `dblib_connect'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:271:in `connect'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:59:in `initialize'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.6/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:18:in `new'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.6/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:18:in `sqlserver_connection'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.2/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.2/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
        from (irb):1
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /apps/acme_dynamite/path/ruby/2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

the working Azure connection looks something like:

```
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_HOST="xxx.database.windows.net"
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PORT=1433
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE="databasename_no_dots"
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_USERNAME="username_no_dots_or_ands"
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PASSWORD="supersecret"
```

the non-working one looks like:

```
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_HOST="xxx2.database.windows.net"
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PORT=1433
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE="other_databasename_no_dots"
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_USERNAME="username_no_dots_or_ands"
env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PASSWORD="supersecret"
```

The problem is not connectivity or a firewall, because I can actually connect to this new Azure server using /node_modules/sql-cli. What could possibly be wrong?  Some incompatibility between my version of Ruby and this other instance of Azure? I am out of ideas.

That pile of errors can be triggered from within irb just by issuing a statement like:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT 1")
```

Comment: "Stack level too deep" implies that a method is somehow calling itself inadvertently. Can you narrow it down to precisely which thing you change that causes the issue? Have you explored upgrading dependencies as this may be a known bug that was solved in a later patch? It's worth trying Rails 4.2.6 and more up-to-date drivers.

Comment: But the only difference in this case is that the database is being served from a different server.  why would changing the location of where the data is served from lead to runaway recursion?  The extremely brittle nature of the Azure-Rails interface makes me very happy I am a Node.js developer.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: the key to getting around this problem turned out to be the creation of a new Azure login/user (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/ ).  While the admin user you might be tempted to work with works fine for some database connections, in Ruby on Rails it is likely to fail in the unhelpful way described above. Trust me, you can avoid a lot of headaches if you set up some other app-specific SQL login first. All this could've been avoided had Ruby on Rails simply reported that the database user had insufficient permissions instead of getting caught in runaway recursion.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

env PRODUCTION_DATABASE_HOST="xxx2.**database**.windows.net"

Comment: i've tried every permutation of the domain and username, sometimes with @s and various numbers of subdomains